# External synchronization of a AD MEMS acceleration sensor (ADXL355)

Tags: sensor, accelerometer, synchronization, mems

sadly, the AD help page was not very helpful therefore I'm posting here with the hope that the collective intelligence here can help me with my problem.

I'm struggling with the external synchronization of the ADXL355. I want to synchronize the [ADXL355](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/adxl354_adxl355.pdf) with an external clock and sync - EXT_SYNC = 01, EXT_CLK = 1. Therefore, I set register 0x2B (43) to 5 and then I start the sensor with setting 0x2D (45) to 0. After that, I provide the sensor with an external clock of 1024kHz on the INT2 pin. 1024.59kHz to be exact because that's the closest clock to 1024kHz I can get with my setup (0.06% accuracy should be good enough). After 256 every pulses (250µs) I supply the sensor with a SYNC signal on the DRDY pin, hence, the DRDY pin is an input in this case (as far as I understand). After the falling edge of the SYNC signal I set the CS to 0 and start with a multibyte read on register 8 (reading x-, y- and z- acceleration data).
When analyzing the waveforms I can't see any violation of the requirements. Nevertheless, I get meaningless readings in the acceleration data. Attached you can find two measurements of a logic analyzer.[image: measurement]

The sensor is mounted on a flat surface, therefore I would expect 1g in z-direction but I get around 0.6g. When I run the sensor with the internal ADC-clock I get meaningful readings.

Do you have any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If I got this right (but I might not), you've disabled the interpolation filter alltogether; can we preclude that filter to have had a gain (of roughly 1/0.6) for DC? If we can't from the datasheet, can you turn your board upside down and measure whether it's -0.6g?

Comment: As far as I understand the datasheet, the interpolation filter is deactivated in this mode (EXT_SYNC = 01, EXT_CLK = 1) therefore I wouldn't expect an influence. I will turn the sensor into various positions next week when the sensor is again available for my tests.

Comment: I turned the sensor upside down. The z-value I read is -1.4 then.

Comment: now *that* is surprising.